# android spinner first element list

Tags: android, spinner

I have the following code:

```
spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,result));
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
String selected;
boolean click=false;
int currSelection =spin.getLastVisiblePosition();
public void onItemSelected(
AdapterView<?> parentView,View selectedItemView, int position,long id)
{
   if ((position != 0)){
  //code here
    }
}
```

When clicking on the **first element** from the list I can't retrieve the value. All the rest of the `list elements` work as expected.

I know that the issue is that int value position. The problem is that if i don't have that if condition then every type i start the list the first element pops up even if i  haven t click on any item of the list. How to solve this?

Comment: so it is the default behavior that it will return 0 if no item selected, It means first item is selected(0th position). What do you want now?

Comment: i want to print the list element when clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to print the list element after click it will be difficult with spinner because android by default selects first element in spinner at 0th location and it will print that element without selection.

For that I can suggest you to use Alert Dialog instead of spinner.Use button instead of spinner and onClick() of button create Alert Dialog.The example is given below.

Create String array of your spinner item.

```
String[] element = {Your element List};
private OnClickListener btn_Listener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Set your Button Name");

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(itemsForHindi, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {                             
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                            selectedParam = element[item].toString(); // Here you can get selected ielement.                                
                        }
                    });
        }           
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
};
```

If you have any doubt ask me.